# Posting JSON to PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, json, post

I am stuck a long time with trying to send a `JSON` from `javascript` to a `PHP` script : the sending is fine (I can see the `JSON` in fiddler) yet I receive nothing in the `PHP script` :

`javascript`:

```
var person = {
  name: 'yoel',
  age: 28
};
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:8888/statisticsdb.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(person));
```

`php` :

```
echo 'trying to print ' . var_dump($_POST["name"]);
```

I would expect obviously to see SOMETHING but var_dump returns nothing. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you could use jQuery, it has a very simple $.post() method where you can simply pass the JSON Object as parameter: $.post('URL',person,success:function())

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump($data->name);
```

the reason for this is, that the body of your POST-request is:

```
{"name":"yoel","age":28}
```

though, php expects something like ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29)):

```
name=yoel&age=28
```

The json string can not be parsed properly, and thus `$_POST` will be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply , much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST` holds value decoded from request having `Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, i.e. it parses:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2
```

into:

```
array( 'param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2')
```

If you send data in json format, you have to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it from the [raw php input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonData = json_decode($input);
```

And you'll have a PHP object filled with your json stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", JSON.stringify(person).length);
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem - there is already an accepted solution, also.